# Add score to saved score

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

when I restart the app and start tapping on the button the saved score is set to 0 and counts up from there how can I change it that it counts up the saved score?

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var TapLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!

    var taps = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            TapLabel.text = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key"))

            Banner.hidden = true
            Banner.delegate = self
            self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        Banner.hidden = false
    }


    @IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){

        taps += 1
        TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(taps, forKey: "key")



    }

}
```

Comment: `taps = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set taps to what is stored in NSUserDefaults. Currently you only set this to the label.

So in your viewDidLoad method, add this:

```
taps = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
```

Then below that add the following to update the display:

```
TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
```

Another way to do this is so make your taps property set and get the user defaults directly. Here is an example:

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var TapLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!

    var taps: Int {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(newValue, forKey: "key")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"

        Banner.hidden = true
        Banner.delegate = self
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        Banner.hidden = false
    }


    @IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){

        taps += 1
        TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the app and restart it there is only the number I reached last time how can I put "Taps:" next to that?

Answer (score 0):

You change this my giving Taps an initial number and then setting it to the previously stored value Below is the code

```
@IBOutlet var TapLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!


var taps: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let previousTaps = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key"))
        TapLabel.text = previousTaps
        taps = Int(previousTaps)
        Banner.hidden = true
        Banner.delegate = self
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    Banner.hidden = false
}


@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){

    taps += 1
    TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(taps, forKey: "key")



}
```